# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal showing in twig file

Tags: symfony, twig

```
{% block reviewresult %}
<div class="scrollerList"> 
</div>

{% endblock %}
{% block myJavascript %}
<script>
    var stateObject = {};
    var title = "Single";
    var urlEncode = "'" +{{ tag|url_encode(true) }} + "'";
    alert(urlEncode);

    var newUrl = baseUrl + "/taglist/" + urlEncode.toString();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        ShuffleObj.changeUrl(stateObject, title, newUrl);

        ffleObj.setScrollUrl(baseUrl + '/taglist/playlist/' + urlEncode.toString());
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

above code in line `var urlEncode = "'" +{{ tag|url_encode(true) }} + "'";` shows the error
**SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal**. In this problem tag value is `tag= 123 Forever;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
var urlEncode = "'" +{{ tag|url_encode(true) }} + "'";
```

will produce following code:

```
var urlEncode = "'" + someTag + "'";
```

And js interpret someTag as identifier. So, try this one instead:

```
var urlEncode = ' {{ tag|url_encode(true) }} ';
```